# Is there a way to manipulate data and put it in specific row/column CELL within a dataframe?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, data-manipulation

I want to pull specific data from one excel sheet(master) and put it in another excel sheet. Putting Example below:

```
Excel1:
SN   Name   Location   Degree   Skill    Skill Value
 1   Nam1   Loc1       Deg1     Skill1   Yes
 2   Nam1   Loc1       Deg1     Skill2   No
 3   Nam2   Loc2       Deg2     Skill1   No
 4   Nam2   Loc2       Deg2     Skill2   Yes


Excel2:
Name   Location   Degree   Skill1   Skill2
Nam1   Loc1       Deg1     Yes      No
Name2  Loc2       Deg2     No       Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in R, then it's pretty easy.

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  select(-SN) %>% 
  spread(key='Skill', value=`Skill Value`)
```

Output:

```
  Name  Location Degree Skill1 Skill2
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1 Nam1  Loc1     Deg1   Yes    No    
2 Nam2  Loc2     Deg2   No     Yes
```